# asp.net mvc4 clientside validation doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have clientside validation enabled in my config and I'm also including the appropriate jquery files for validation, but every time I submit, the page posts to server without first doing clientside validation.  I have pasted the markup generated in the source below.  It seems to be generating the data- validation messages fine.  Just somehow not triggering validation.

I'm using the BeginCollection library that's available on Nuget to build my dynamic form.  Could that be a reason for my clientside validation for somehow not working?

```
    <input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" 
data-val-number="The field DaysAbsent must be a number." 
data-val-required="The DaysAbsent field is required." 
id="students_471abdc8-b190-42da-9f72-ed30a1e33b10__DaysAbsent" 
name="students[471abdc8-b190-42da-9f72-ed30a1e33b10].DaysAbsent" 
type="text" value="0">
```

---

My web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

---

_Layout.cshtml:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

---

BundleConfig.cs:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Comment: What's this `BeginCollection` library? Never heard of it. But most importantly is it a server side or a client side library?

Comment: Do you have Microsoft's `unobtrusive-validation` included?

Comment: @darin begincollection is a serverside library.  It's what generated the long Id and Name above.

Comment: sparky, yes as far as I know.  I'm editing above to show code.

Comment: `~/Scripts/jquery.validate*` should be bundled before `~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive`

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned dynamic form, so if you are loading your inputs dynamically jquery.validate doesn't know they are there. You have to "refresh" your form validations to validate your new inputs.

After adding a new input, use this code to "refresh" the validations for your form:

```
$('form').removeData('validator');
$('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
```